# data type for a varchar2(25 byte) and number(50) in oracle 11g

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jpa

hi I'm using a database from oracle 11g, some colummns have varchar2(1 byte) and some others have number(15) as a data type, i'm using JPA with spring-mvc and i need to create a class for each table that i have in the database, and i dont know what java's data type should i put for this colummns, i'm thinking of putting int for the number(15) colummns and byte for the varchar2(1 byte) and varchar2(25 byte) colummn, but i am not too sure.

in the database:

```
charts_ids           NUMBER(15)
flag_details         VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
```

in my java class:

```
 @Column (name="charts_ids", nullable=false)
 private int charts_ids;

    @Column (name="flag_details", nullable=false)
    private byte flag_details;
```

Comment: You need to use `String` for `varchar2` (or `varchar`) For `varchar2(1)` _maybe_ a `char`. But `byte` is definitely the wrong choice (because the column stores a character, not a byte)

Comment: What is the largest value of your number(15) column, because 10^15-1 is not going to fit in an int (32-bit signed).  So, you probably want to use a long.

Comment: oldProgrammer my number(15) i think it have to 900k, thanks a_horse_with_no_name and  OldProgrammer
i'm going to use long instead of int and String instead of byte.

Comment: Don't forget to use class type `Long` and not `long`. That is true for all fields. It is a good practice.